# How to pass in Owner's name and email parameters to VeracodeAPI.create_app method

Tags: python, veracode

Unable to add Business Owner, Owner Email, Re-enter Email Parameters, While creating app.

Do we have any veracode_api?

Trying to pass -> VeracodeAPI.create_app("self", app_name_input, business_criticality_input, teams=['Hello'], business_owner = "xyz", Owner_Email = "xyz@xx.com")

returns _rest_request raise requests.exceptions.RequestException() requests.exceptions.RequestException

Answer (score 0):

I'm the maintainer of `veracode-api-py`.

The method `create_app` in this library does not currently support supplying business owner name or email, as you can see in the [documentation](https://github.com/veracode/veracode-api-py/blob/main/docs/applications.md). The library does accept pull requests, and I've [recorded this request as an issue](https://github.com/veracode/veracode-api-py/issues/73) if someone wants to add it.

Comment: The `create_app` and `update_app` methods have been updated to accept business owner name and email as optional parameters; note that both must be provided if you want to use either. A new version of the library will be released this Friday containing the update.